# Why a O(logn) slower than O(n) function?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I met a strange issue when I solve codechef problem [Lowest Sum](https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA04/problems/LOWSUM/).

There is area of codes to calculate the numbers of pair(i,j) which sum(a[i]+a[j])<X, the idea is to enumerate each a[i], accumulate the numbers which smaller than X-a[i] in vector b. there are two ways to find the number smaller than X-a[i] in vector b:

1. O(n):

```
for(int i=0; i<K&&mid-a[i]>=b[0]; i++) {
    int j=K-1;
    while(j>=0 && mid-a[i]<b[j]) {
        --j;
    }
    ans+=j+1;
}
```

2. O(logn)

```
for(int i=0; i<K&&mid-a[i]>=b[0]; i++) {
    auto it = upper_bound(b.begin(), b.end(), mid-a[i]);
    ans += it-b.begin();
}
```

O(logn) should be faster than O(n), but O(n) can passed within 2s and O(logn) TLE. What's the reason? Thanks in advance.

The code for your reference:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
using ll = long long;
int T, K, Q;
int main() {
    scanf("%lld", &T);
    while(T--) {
        cin >> K >> Q;
        vector<ll> a(K), b(K);
        for(int i=0; i<K; i++) {
            scanf("%lld", &a[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<K; i++) {
            scanf("%lld", &b[i]);
        }
        sort(a.begin(), a.end());
        sort(b.begin(), b.end());
        
        while(Q-->0) {
            int qu;
            scanf("%d", &qu);
            
            ll low = a[0]+b[0];
            ll high = a[K-1]+b[K-1];
            ll ans = high;
            while(low<=high) {
                ll mid = (low+high)/2;
                int cnt = 0, j=K-1;
                for(int i=0; i<K&&mid-a[i]>=b[0]; i++) {
                    /*
                    // can pass within 2 seconds
                    while(j>=0 && b[j]>mid-a[i]) j--;
                    cnt += j+1;
                    */
                    
                    // TLE 
                    auto it = upper_bound(b.begin(), b.end(), mid-a[i]);
                    cnt += it-b.begin();
                    
                }
                if(cnt>=qu) {
                    ans = mid;
                    high=mid-1;
                }else {
                    low=mid+1;
                }
            }
            printf("%lld\n", ans);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regardless of the code, big-O doesn't automatically determine speed. There's always a constant factor and it can be sufficiently large to determine the result up to some approximate value of n.

Comment: constant factor should be trivial while n is large,  the n should be 20000 in this problem. the constraint: 
1 ≤ K ≤ 20000
1 ≤ Q ≤ 500
1 ≤ qi ( for i = 1 to Q ) ≤ 10000
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^18 ( for i = 1 to K )
1 ≤ Bi ≤ 10^18 ( for i = 1 to K )

Comment: Your O(log n) code is likely not correct. Run it with your debugger to trace its operation. At the very least rewrite it to be readable. The descriptionless variable names and allergy to whitespace make my eyes glaze over.

Comment: I have rewrite it and sorry for the inconvenient. I went through the code you mentioned and I think it's correct. the functionality of this code is to find the numbers lower and equal to x-a[i], upper_bound()-v.begin() can obtain the number regardless head or tail.

Comment: "I went through the code you mentioned and I think it's correct" obviously it's not if it's hanging. Extract only the algorithm in question from your code and run it with your own inputs. It's failing. Find out where.

Comment: Post minimally-reproducible examples of your algorithms.

Comment: @harrisondong: you initialize `j` only once outside the `i` loop; therefore you're actually comparing `O(n)` vs `O(n log n)`, and that's assuming they do the same thing.

Comment: @YakovGalka you are correct, i got it. thanks a lot.

Comment: The universe is O(1) and we've been at it for 13.5 billion years so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "code for reference" initializes `j` only once **outside the `i` loop**. Thus, if uncommented, the "O(n)" version actually looks like:

```
int j=K-1;              // <----------- HERE
for(int i=0; i<K&&mid-a[i]>=b[0]; i++) {
    //int j=K-1;        // <----------- NOT HERE
    while(j>=0 && mid-a[i]<b[j]) {
        --j;
    }
    ans+=j+1;
}
```

This gives an amortized `O(1)` runtime for the inner loop, because `j` can be decremented at most `K` times. Compared to the `O(log K)` for the TLE version.

Put it other way, the runtime of the entire `for(int i...)` loop is `O(K)` in the first case, versus `O(K log K)` in the second.

Comment: Thanks guy, it's very helpful to understand.